# Merge sort for GPU

Tags: algorithm, opencl, gpu, mergesort

Im trying to implement a merge sort using opencl wrapper.

The problem is, each pass needs a different indexing algorithm for threads' memory access.

Some info about this:

```
First pass(numbers indicate elements and arrows indicate sorting)
0<-->1   2<--->3  4<--->5  6<--->7

group0   group1    group2   group3  ===>1 thread per group, N/2 groups total

Second pass(all parallel)
0<------>2        4<------>6
     1<------->3       5<------->7

   group0            group1  ========> 2 threads per group, N/4 groups

Next pass
0<--------------->4                   8<------------------>12
     1<--------------->5                     9<------------------->13
         2<--------------->6                         10<---------------->14
               3<--------------->7                          11<--------------->15

       group0                                  group1  ===>4 threads per group
                                                          but N/8 groups
```

So, an element of a sub-group cannot make any comparison between another group's element.

I cannot simply do

```
A[i]<---->A[i+1]  or A[i]<---->A[i+4]
```

because these cover

```
A[1]<---->A[2] and A[4]<----->A[8]
```

which are wrong.

I needed a more complex indexing algorithm which has potential **to use same number of threads for all passes**.

```
Pass n:  global id(i): 0,1,  2,3  4,5 , ...  to compare id  0,1   4,5    8,9    
looks like compare id1=(i/2)*4+i%2

Pass n+1: global id(i): 0,1,2,3,  4,5,6,7, ... to compare id 0,1,2,3,   8,9,10,11,    16,17   
looks like  compare id=(i/4)*8+i%4

Pass n+2: global id(i): 0,1,2,3,... 8,9,10,... to compare id  0,1,2,3,... 16,17,18,...     
looks like  compare id=(i/8)*16+i%8

compare id1 = (  i/( pow(2,passN) )  ) * pow(2,passN+1) + i%( pow(2, passN) )
compare id2 = compare id1 + pow(2,passN)
```

so, in the kernel string, can it be

```
int i=get_global_id(0);
int compareId1=(  i/( pow(2,passN) )  ) * pow(2,passN+1) + i%( pow(2, passN) );
int compareId2=compareId1+pow(2,passN);
if(compareId1!=compareId2)
{
    if(A[compareId1]>A[compareId2])
    {
          xorSwapIdiom(A,compareId1,compareId2,B);
    }
    else
   {
          streamThrough(A,compareId1,compareId2,B);
    }
}
else
{
       // this can happen only for the first pass
       // needs a different kernel structure for that
}

    but Im not sure.
```

**Question:** Can you give any directions about which memory access pattern would not leak while satisfying the "no compare between different groups" condition?

Needed to hard-reset my computer many times already, trying different algortihms(memory leaked, black screen, crash, restart), this one is the last and I fear it can crash entire OS.

I already tried a much simpler version with a decreasing number of threads per pass, had some bad performance.

Edit: I tried the upper code,  it sorts reversely ordered arrays. But not randomized arrays.

Comment: If sorting algorithm itself isn't principal, try bitonic sort. It benefits a lot from local memory & you don't need to write code, there are a lot of samples available.

Comment: Is the reason you chose merge sort purely academic? It does not seem like the most appropriate algorithm to use.

Comment: Im just trying some uniform pass type sorting that lets each core do equal amount of work. Not academic. Just trying if I can help any database sorting action with this. Ill look into bitonic sort too.